# Change index based on the lowest value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers

Is there a function in JavaScript that allows me to change the index? For example, I have 4 values ​​in an array:

```
var arr = [10, -20, 20, 30]
```

Now I want to set the lowest value as the first index and the following after the same pattern. The index should be for the example above:

```
[-20, 10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: so what is the question about? sorting? or moving (only) the first element?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to sort the array. The default JS sort uses string-based comparisons. You need to provide your own comparator function for numeric comparisons:

```js
var arr = [10, -20, 20, 30]

arr.sort((i, j) => i - j)

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Your sorting method is quite silly when `(i, j) => i - j` suffices, and besides, if this is the answer then there are plenty of duplicates to close this with, no need to answer it again.

Comment: Thanks ic3b3rg "Sort" is what I was looking for.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ok, thanks - that's a better comparator, I updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the index of the smallest value, splice it and unshift this value.

The result does not alter the order of other elements, like with sort.

```js
var array = [10, -20, 20, 30],
    index = array.reduce((r, v, i, a) => a[r] < v ? r : i, 0);

array.unshift(array.splice(index, 1)[0]);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nina, that's also a cool way to do that!